# Position of querystring parameters on friendly url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I dont know why this is not working in this htaccess rule:
I want that friendly url can get 2 querystring params and it works fine, but the problem is the  position that each param has in querystring.

I cant know the exact position of $2 and $3.

This is the url to try...
http://myweb.com/ferrari-testarossa-car-id460?aa=red&bb=coupe

And this is my rule...

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-\+\.]+-id([0-9]{1,5})[\?]?([a-z0-9\-\_]*[\=]?[a-z0-9]*[\.]?[a-z0-9]*)&([a-z0-9\-\_]*[\=]?[a-z0-9]*[\.]?[a-z0-9]*)$ car-profile.php?idModel=$1&$2&$3 [QSA,L]
```

I would need to pass key and value (both together) like this "**aa=red**" y "**bb=coupe**" to destination url as $2 and $3

How can i do this?

1000 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally.....I got it!

This is the correct regular expression:

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-\+\.]+-id([0-9]{1,5})?$ car-profile.php?idModel=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When we put the flag "**[QSA]**", entire querystring will be passed concatenated to $ 1 parameter, so, into your php page, you can get each value within typical $GET["param"]

Example:  for this input url:

```html
http://myweb.com/ferrari-testarossa-car-id460?bb=coupe&&aa=red
```

this will be got as output url:

```html
http://myweb.com/car-profile.php?idModel=460?bb=coupe&&aa=red
```

It was easier than i thought.

Thnaks a lot for everyone

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/.*id=(\d+)\?aa=([^&]*)&bb=(.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ car-profile.php?idModel=%1&%2&%3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Ok however in your example aa is in 1st position and bb on second position.... but i want to can pass these params on not predefined positions..... sorry my english

Comment: @mdromed, ok could you please explain more on this one? By giving some examples/sample of URLs here.

Comment: I want treat params from query string with  no order position:  `?aa=red&bb=coupe` will be same to `bb=coupe&&aa=red`

Comment: @mdromed, I got it but let's say `ferrari-testarossa-car-id460?aa=red&bb=coupe` OR `ferrari-testarossa-car-id460?bb=red&aa=coupe` in both cases it should be passed like `car-profile.php?idModel=%1&%2&%3` like that only? If not then what should be their sequence? I am also considering that you have only aa and bb string nothing else as of now, let me know on same.

Comment: Hi again...  i had probed your code on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ but it is not working...  Can you test your code there?

Comment: @mdromed, I am sorry to say, but those sites are not good, when I tested these rules in my local those worked just fine.

Comment: ok ok perfect!  I will do  too.   Thank you very much!

Comment: Last ask.... Is there any way to see resultant url?